# How to alter byCategory projection via API?

Tags: eventstoredb

I want to set my `$byCategory` system projection to `last` in [EventStore](https://eventstore.org/docs/projections/system-projections/). Is there any way to do this automatically? Either via a startup configuration or an API call?

It is found under this url on localhost:

http://localhost:2113/web/index.html#/projections/http://localhost:2113/projection/$by_category

Here is what the edit screen looks like:

[image]

Comment: What client are you using? in net client there is something like `var pManager = new ProjectionsManager(new NullLogger(), http, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));` and I use that to enable and manipulate projections when I need to work with event store. There is also a strongly typed way to do it. Have you considered making your own projection for this?